# whether value is repeated in database?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
IF EXISTS ( 'SELECT ' +@TextField+','+@ValueField+' FROM ' + @TableName + ' WHERE ' + @TextFieldPara + '=' +@ValueFieldPara + ' ORDER BY ' +@TextField+' ASC;')
  BEGIN
     SET @Message = @TextField + ' Already Exist...'
  END
ELSE
  BEGIN
    SET @Message = 'TRUE'
  END
```

by using this query i am trying to check in all table whether inserted value for field Repeated or Not.

when i write this query in store procedure i got an error at

> IF EXISTS ( 'SELECT ' +@TextField+','+@ValueField+' FROM ' + @TableName + ' WHERE ' + @TextFieldPara + '=' +@ValueFieldPara + ' ORDER BY ' +@TextField+' ASC;') "

all variables are populated from c# back end.

is there any solution?

Comment: I don't know where those variables are being populated from, but, as it stands, that query looks like a SQL injection wet dream. On a different note, what is your question?

Comment: After concatenation you have a string literal. Not command/statement. This is called _Dynamic SQL_. You might want to a) concatenate if first on C# side and run as ad-hoc query or b) execute this code as dynamic sql on server side.

Comment: use GROUP BY and COUNT. And by the way, the ORDER BY in your code is a useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set the table, you need dynamic SQL.  Here is one method:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);
declare @cnt int;

set @sql = '
SELECT @cnt = COUNT(*)
FROM @TableName
WHERE @TextFieldPara = @ValueFieldPara
');

set @sql = replace(@sql, '@TableName', @TableName);
set @sql = replace(@sql, '@TextFieldPara', @TextFieldPara);
set @sql = replace(@sql, '@ValueFieldPara', @ValueFieldPara);

exec sp_executesql(@sql, N'@cnt int output', @cnt=@cnt output);

if (@cnt > 0) . . .
  begin
     set @Message = @TextField + ' Already Exist...';
  end
else
  begin
    set @Message = 'TRUE';
  end;
```

I simplified the query because you don't need a `select` list or `order by` for determining the existing of values.  I also used `count(*)` just because it is simpler to express.  If you care about performance, there are better methods, such as a `case` with an `exists` in it.

Similarly, you should use `quotename()` for the identifiers in the query.  You don't have that in your sample code, but it is a best practice.

Comment: I'd recommend using `QUOTENAME` there. That query is still open to injection as it is (considering we don't know how the variable values are passed in).